# Recalculate and replace large table without interrupting table reads

Tags: select, locking, azure-sql-database

There's a large table in the database containing statistical information. This table must be read frequently (by lookups which return a single row).

This table must be completely recalculated every so often. There's a procedure which does the calculation. Currently it does this into a temporary table, and then when it's done it truncates the real table and inserts the data from the temporary table into it.

The problem is that this truncation and insertion takes a while and interrupts lookups during that time. The question is how to do it without interrupting lookups, or only interrupting lookups very briefly.

I'd be happy to hear all options which achieve the desired behaviour; the solution doesn't necessarily have to involve a temporary table. Sorry if this is an established common problem -- I wasn't sure which terms to search.

Answer (score 2):

Two options, depending on the engine and/or the permissions you have - populate a second table, then rename that table (e.g. `sp_rename 'thetable', 'deadtable'; sp_rename 'newtable', 'thetable'; drop table deadtable;`), or populate a second table then have your *application* choose to use that table instead.

Comment: Possibly a silly question -- do those operations effectively happen at the same time? That is, there's not a brief downtime between renaming 'thetable' and 'newtable' during which no table is named 'thetable' and lookups fail?

Comment: @Denziloe - Most db engines are pretty good at blocking/queuing when they need to. As long as your app isn't too sensitive to a short wait, it may be OK. There's always going to be a transition; the aim is to make that transition short enough that your app doesn't suffer. Renaming or repointing is likely to be far quicker than delete-and-reload.

Comment: I suggest you also nest the drop/rename operations into an explicit transaction which should further limit issues.

Answer (score 0):

Much data can be moved between tables quickly using partition switching. Even if you haven't defined partitioning explicitly this will work. From the documentation, each table has a [default partition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-db-partition-stats-transact-sql#remarks)

> If a heap or index is not partitioned, it is made up of one partition

This requires three tables: Working, which has the values currently being consumed by the application. Old, to which the current values will be switched to empty Working, removing the need to TRUNCATE. And New where the new set of values will be calculated in advance of being switched.

A real solution is not required to use these exact names, of course. I choose them simply to highlight the roles they play in the implementation.

First some dummy tables with some data to show the current state.

```
drop table if exists Old;
drop table if exists Working;
drop table if exists New;

create table Old(c int);
create table Working(c int);
create table New(c int);

Insert Working(c) values (1), (2), (3);

select 'Old', * from Old;
select 'Working', * from Working;
select 'New', * from New;
```

Old and New are empty. Working contains the values the application consumes during normal operation. Next we perform the recalculation into New

```
Insert New(c) values (11), (22), (33);
```

To move the data we employ two SWITCH statements. The first moves all rows from Working to Old, leaving Working empty. The second moves all rows from New to Working, leaving New empty.

```
begin transaction
   alter table Working switch to Old;
   alter table New switch to Working;
commit
```

The target of a SWITCH (the table to which data is being moved) must be empty before the SWITCH is executed. The first SWITCH empties Working ready to receive the new data in the second SWITCH. Having the transaction ensures locks are held between statements, preventing the application from seeing an empty table.

Having Old is not strictly necessary. Without it, though, Working would have to be truncated during the swap-over cycle which, as you've noted, is slow. With Old, the old data can be dealt with off the critical path, without affecting the application. It *does* have to be dealt with, though. By the next execution cycle Old must be empty else the above will fail.

While the switches are happening read operations cannot progress against Working. The application is blocked. There will be a spike in latency. However, SWITCH works by changing metadata in the catalogue, not by actually moving rows around on disk. The switches should be very quick and the latency spike short-lived.